# Deleting an object declared on the stack

Tags: c++

I wanted to know what happens if we delete an object declared on the stack, two times. In order to test this I've written this simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A() {}
    virtual ~A() {
        cout << "test" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.~A();
}
```

I was actually expecting a segmentation fault, as I'm deleting A once explicitly in the code, and it will be deleted again when it goes out of scope, however suprisingly the program produces the following ouput:

> > "test"
> >     "test"

Can anybody explain why this code is working??

Comment: it's UB. Any surprise?

Comment: No you are not "deleting" the local variable `a`, you are just calling the destructor function. In short you can not "delete" a local variable. If you want it to be destructed use scoping or dynamic allocation.

Comment: the destructor is nothing more than a regular member function (that you called in your case, with `.~A()`) the difference is that the destructor is called (hiddenly) at the end of the scope, in your case at the end of `main()` right "before" `}`

Comment: Causing an objects destructor to be invoked twice is Undefined Behaviour - the compiler is allowed to do whatever it wants. It's a bug and you simply should not do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three reasons:

1. The destructor does not deallocate the object, it performs whatever cleanup operation you find useful (and by default, nothing). It is implicitly called before a variable goes out of scope or is explicitly deleted, but you are free to call it as well.
2. Deallocation usually does not cause memory to cease existing nor to be inaccessible. It is rather marked as reusable. (Anyway, double deallocation should raise a memory management error condition.)
3. Last but not least, an object allocated on the stack is not deallocated (when you exit the function, the stack pointer moves to the previous frame, leaving the stack unchanged).

Comment: The default-generated destructor actually does do something; it calls the destructors of members.

Answer (score 3):

Your program has undefined behaviour, so it may just as easily have segfaulted, or stolen my car, or gone into space to start an exciting new colony of lesbian parrots.

But, in practice, the behaviour you've witnessed can be explained. Calling the destructor does not "delete" an object; it just calls the destructor. A destructor call is one part of object deletion; yours just prints to standard output, so there's really nothing to trigger a memory access violation here.

More generally, "expecting a segmentation fault" is *always* folly.

However, if you'd *actually* attempted to delete the object with `delete`, I would be surprised if your program didn't crash at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You called the destructor of a. This does not delete the variable, it just call the destructor function. The variable will be remove from the stack at the exit of the function.

Answer (score 0):

As the name says, `a` is a "*variable with automatic lifetime*" which means you can't end it's lifetime prematurely yourself. It is bound to the scope it was created in. You're just manually calling the destructor which is just another method that prints something. Then it's called again automatically by the runtime on actual destruction and end of lifetime. You can *somewhat* control the lifetime of an automatically managed object by defining the scope of it:

```
int main()
{
    {
      A a;
    } // 'a' is destroyed here.
} // instead of here.
```